# Questions on synchronous ZeroMQ pipeline architecture

Tags: queue, message-queue, zeromq

So, i built this small example of a ZeroMQ pipeline architecture because i'll end up having to do something similar very soon and i'm trying to grasp the pipeline concept the right way.

https://gist.github.com/2765708

Right now, this is completely asynchronous. The controller dispatches a batch of tasks to various workers, which in their turn, send a message to the sink. The controller and sink are fixed parts of my architecture, while workers are dynamic. That's perfect.

However, i would like to know when the workers have finished working on all their tasks. In that example, i do know the amount of messages, but that won't be true on real-life situations. I might have 100 messages or 10,000. So, how can the sink or the controller know when the workers have finished working on their tasks? I have to perform some actions that depend on the conclusion of the jobs sent to workers.

Comment: This is what a semaphore is good for. It will need to be a distributed semaphore, but 'A' will increment the semaphore and 'B' will decrement it. If the semaphore count ever exceeds X, 'A' waits until it becomes less than X to post more jobs. Of course 'A' doesn’t have to wait, it can be used just to know how many tasks are left to be completed. This will solve your problem if your using a sink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I wanted to expand on @bjlaub's answer. It started as a comment but I was typing too much. I agree with the concept of acknowledgment, but believe it can originate in multiple places*.

There are multiple approaches to this communication and it all depends on the behavior you are after in the system.

First, you can either send out messages from the workers as they finish each task, or from the sink as it receives each task. Right now I am not addressing the type of socket, only the act of communicating. I believe it is much more efficient to send it from the sink as you would only need one connection back to the controller instead of one for each worker. The sink does not need to know how many total tasks there are. Only that it is firing off a message after each result it receives. The controller can determine how many to expect since it was the submission point and new when it had exhausted its submission (the count).

Now regardless of whether you have the message sent from the worker or the sink, you can use different socket types. If you want the controller to completely block until all work is done, then you can have it be a push/pull until it receives X messages (message content can be anything. Its just a trigger).

This may be limiting if the controller wants to be able to do other work while these tasks are happening. If so, you could maybe use pub/sub, and let the controller subscribe to being notified as tasks complete, and asynchronously maintain a count until the total has been satisfied.

And finally, maybe you have the situation where you want the controller to ask the sink for a status when you deem fit. You can have a req/rep pattern for the controller to ask the sink how many requests it has received on demand.

I'm sure one of these patterns will fit your specific needs.

Comment: +1 - Hadn't considered having the sink send the acknowledgement..that will certainly improve performance!  It also might be worth noting you could still use a PULL socket in the controller and just use non-blocking I/O (with `zmq_poll`) if it needs to do other work while waiting for the acks.

Comment: @bjlaub: That is true. You could poll the socket regardless. It really does just come down to how exactly you want the communication path to function.

Comment: I don't really need feedback on each task, i just need to know when all workers have finished working on their assigned tasks.

Comment: @KlausS.: Are you saying this info isn't what you were looking for? There is no way for the workers to  know how much work they should be expecting without making them bound more closely to the controller. Only the controller should know how much work it has in total.

Comment: Ok, so i have to make the controller PUSH to the sink and make the sink count the amount of responses from workers and see if it matches the number PUSHed by the controller?

Comment: @KlausS.: No, the sink does not need to have any knowledge of the total at all. Its already receiving responses from the workers as they finish each task anyways. So all you have to do is ping a socket back to the controller. The controller already knew how many jobs it sent out and its just getting back notifications as they finish. The only one that knows the total is the controller the whole time. Your workers can stay completely independent as well.

Answer (score 1):

One idea (disclaimer: I have very little experience w/ 0MQ!):

Setup an "acknowledgment" pipeline in the reverse direction.  Since the controller presumably knows how many tasks it has dispatched to the workers (e.g. the number of times it called `send`), it can use a PULL socket to receive a small message (an integer for example) from each worker indicating the completion of the task.  The worker process dispatches its completed result to the sink, and at the same time sends the acknowledgement back to the controller.  Once the controller collects the right number of acknowledgements, it can do whatever post-processing is necessary before farming out the next set of work.

You could also push this downstream to the sink, but you would need to notify the sink of the total number of work units to expect *before* farming them out to the workers.